# Phishing site under the name ubuntu.org

Tags: discussion, website

I just looking for Ubuntu iso's, so I typed `cdimage ubuntu` on the search bar. Found this site called `cdimage.ubuntu.org`, I didn't see the `.org`, so I just clicked it.

My uBlock origin warned me to not go any further, some filter blacklist the site apparently.

[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/d3f12a7919640557c5a146a8c812ce53c8ffdbaa6b78d5ff47d23b9da2cfe69e/detection) engine also give `Phishing` to classify the site. Just a heads up..

Comment: I don't think Ask Ubuntu or SE could do anything in this regard. If it was reproducing the content of AU without citing, then it would have been concern of SE. You can rather contact the search engine about the site so that it can stop showing it in search results.

Comment: This isn't about Ask Ubuntu, so I am closing this as OT.  Contact the Canonical legal team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems a trademark infringement to me.

See https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/intellectual-property-policy

> 8. Contact us
>
> Please contact us:
>
> - to report a breach of our IPRights Policy.

and https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/contact-us